# Azure AppGW: Route to a specific URL Path

Tags: azure, iis, web-applications, azure-application-gateway

Currently having web apps hosting in IIS and Azure application gateway is getting used for all the routing to different servers.

What I am trying to achieve is if we get a request on https://contoso.com then it should be redirected to https://constoso.com/Check_Module/login.aspx. (Have multiple modules and want to navigate to one specific one).

Any suggestion to achieve it via application gateway or similar approach?

Answer (score 0):

For this requirement, you can use url rewrite of IIS.

First, [install](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) url rewrite extension, and then you can find this module in your IIS as below screenshot.

[image]

Then double click "URL Rewrite" and "Add Rule(s)" --> "Blank rule"

[image]

Then create the rule as:

[image]

After that, you can redirect from `https://contoso.com` to `https://constoso.com/Check_Module/login.aspx`